# Nighwatch ignores await in tests

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I'm trying to start with Nightwatch and faced the unclear behavior.

Please take a look at the the following code. I want to gather some text from a page into the list and then print it. Note the `async` test and `await browser.perform` call:

```
module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['smoke test'],
    'Work with a table': async browser => {
        browser.page.mainPage.tablePage().navigate();
        let list = []
        await browser
            .perform(function () {
                browser.elements('css selector', 'thead th', function (elements) {
                    elements.value.forEach(function (elementsObj, index) {
                        browser.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function (result) {
                            list.push(result.value)
                            console.log('>> ' + result.value);
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        console.log('list: ' + list);
        console.log('end');
    }
}
```

In my understanding, I should see the result of `console.log('list: ' + list)` as a fulfilled list at the end of the test.
But the output is:

```
\ Running Work with a table:
list:
| Running Work with a table:
>> Name
>> Position
>> Office
>> Age
>> Start date
‼ Running Work with a table:

No assertions ran.
```

So the  `console.log('list: ' + list);` was executed before. What I'm doing wrong here?

Another one question is why the last `console.log('end');` is not printed at all?

**Update**
I  tried to name the test as `'Work with a table': async function(browser)`, with the same result. And if I add the `await` keyword to the `browser.page.mainPage.tablePage().navigate();` command, there is no console log printed at all.

**Update2**
The result of `broser.perform` is a Promise,
[image]

When I print it, I get the following:

```
Promise {
  <pending>,
  capabilities: {
  acceptInsecureCerts: false,
  acceptSslCerts: false,
  applicationCacheEnabled: false,
  browserConnectionEnabled: false,
  . . .
```

Comment: I didn't find the documentation for `browser.perform`, but I guess it does not return a Promise (you could try that out, by console.log-ing the `browser.perform` return value). If it's not a promise, then `await` simply resolves the returned value and doesn't wait for anything

Comment: @A_A it seems to be a promise, please see my Update2. The API reference for .perform is here https://nightwatchjs.org/api/perform.html

Comment: Ok, you're right there. My next guess would be, that something inside the callback function you pass as argument to `perform` is asynchronous, so `perform` thinks it is finished even though some asynchronous code is not yet finished. If that's the case you likely need the `done` callback described in the API reference and call it when everything inside is finished. I don't have enough Nightwatch experience to help you with this, though